# How to retrieve all external id fields of account object?

Tags: apex, custom-field, externalid

I have a class

```
public static List<AccFieldWrapper> AcctFields(String Account){
       
        Map <String,Schema.SObjectType> mapobject = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType sobjType = mapobject.get('Account');
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result1 = sobjType.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> MapofField = result1.fields.getMap();
        System.debug(MapofField);
        
        List<AccFieldWrapper>accWrapper = new List<AccFieldWrapper>();
        
        for(String fieldName : MapofField.keySet()) {
            Schema.SObjectField field = MapofField.get(fieldName);
            AccFieldWrapper obj = new AccFieldWrapper();
            obj.ApiName = fieldName;
            obj.Label = MapofField.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
            System.debug(obj.Label);
            accWrapper.add(obj);
        }
       
        return accWrapper;
    }

    public class AccFieldWrapper{
       public string ApiName;
       public string Label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get fields of the account a filter them by `isExternalId` like so.

```
for (SObjectField sObjectField : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
    if (sObjectField.getDescribe().isExternalId()) {
        System.debug(sObjectField.getDescribe().getLabel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you also please help me with this

Comment: How to dynamically pass the parameters for upsert operation mainly external id needs to be dynamic?